# Knowing the number of records in table without loading it

Tags: performance, cakephp, orm

I want to know the number of records inside a table without loading them.

This is my actual code :

```
$this->loadModel('Image');
$numberOfRecords = count($this->Image->find('all'));
```

But this is very ugly since It will load all records.

Is there a way of counting records without loading them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not checking the book?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-count

```
$this->loadModel('Image');
$numberOfRecords = $this->Image->find('count'));
```